# Backing up a ZFS pool on a laptop

Tags: usb, backup, zfs, laptop

I have been happily using ZFS pools on laptops for a few years, doing backups on an external drive containing a second pool. But recently, I switched from macOS to Linux, and discovered ZFS on USB drives to be extremely unreliable. I suspect I am running into [this issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9130), but whatever the ultimate cause is, it's not something I can fix, nor something I expect to be fixed soon since I have to stick with Ubuntu 20.04 for various reasons. So I am looking for alternatives.

I would appreciate feedback on the following ideas, as well as different proposals. I am not considering online backups here, the backup must be on a disk that is fully under my control.

1. Use something else than a USB drive. Problem: my laptop only has USB-A and USB-C (plus HDMI) as external connectors.
2. Format the external drive as ext4 (or whatever else) and create a ZFS pool in a sparse file occupying that entire file system. I hesitate because all documentation I can find on this says that pools in a file system are only for small-scale experiments. Without ever being explicit about what the issues are. If it's only a matter of performance, I can live with that.
3. Use a different OS just for the backups, the obvious candidate being FreeBSD. Due to the huge upfraont investment (in time), I hesitate to try this without a prior estimate of the chance of success.

UPDATE: I had a spare USB drive at hand, so I tried option 2. Whatever its other inconveniences may be, it has the same problem as direct ZFS access: after a while the `zfs receive` process hangs and cannot be killed.

Comment: Do you have another USB port on your laptop? preferably on a different controller (e.g. usb3 vs usb2)?  Or can you backup over a network to another machine?   (perhaps beg/buy/scavenge enough parts to build a machine to take zfs snapshots over the network, or a VM on an existing machine).   BTW, what version of zfs are you running? and kernel version?

Comment: There's an interesting comment by dm17 on Oct 3 on that 9130 issue link, speculating that it might be related to power-saving on USB ports.   Perhaps try disabling auto power management for your USB port(s).  See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.14/driver-api/usb/power-management.html - set `/sys/bus/usb/devices/......../power/control` to `on` rather than `auto` for your USB drive.  and maybe set `.../power/autosuspend_delay_ms` to a negative number so it never auto-suspends.

Comment: If that works, these settings will have to be changed every time the USB drive is plugged in, you should be able to automate it with a udev rule.

Comment: Other USB port: there's a USB-C port, to which I can connect a hub with another USB-A to which I could connect the drive. Something worth trying perhaps. I have no idea about controllers behind these ports - it's a laptop after all.

Power management: I have been keeping the machine alive with `caffeinate` for the complete backup process. Not sure this prevents power management processes specific to USB - this is the first time I ever heard about them! Worth trying as well!

Comment: Forgive me if I missed it, but is this a USB-interfaced spinning magnetic disk, or a USB "thumb drive"?  Perhaps either way, assuming the drive is not yet in production use, try a bulk write to the USB drive with `dd`, and see what throughput you get.  I've had failing thumb drives get worse and worse in terms of write performance.

Comment: I have tried to magnetic disks, a new 2 TB Toshiba drive and a somewhat older (a few years) 3 TB LaCie drive. Same problem.

As for @cas' question about remote backup: I did a small test with a remote backup to a Mac, to which I connected the exact same external disk. Worked fine for my 30 GB test dataset. On my Linux laptop, I get stuck after at most 8 GB.

In summary: the external disk works fine on another machine (still ZFS), send/receive on the internal SSD works fine, but receive to the external disk connected locally doesn't. No matter if pure ZFS or ZFS on ext2.

Comment: Some more info: `zfs --version` returns
```zfs-0.8.3-1ubuntu12.13
zfs-kmod-2.0.3-8ubuntu8```
and my kernel version is 5.13.0. I looked at `/sys` to explore the possibility of autosuspend, but it is disabled for my drive.

Comment: One more test: I kept the drive spinning by running `ls` in a loop on another partition. The loop is still running, but the `zfs receive` process got stuck after 7 GB. So this doesn't look like a power management issue.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you just save the `zfs send` snapshots to files on an external ext4 drive (i.e. don't pipe into `zfs recv`, just redirect to a file)?  If yes, then it's the USB drive, driver or controller.  If not then it's ZFS in combination with that USB drive, driver or controller.    Also, can you upgrade ZFS to 2.0.x or 2.1.x? 0.8.3 is kind of ancient, and there have been numerous bug-fixes and performance improvements since then.

Comment: `zfs send` redirected to a file works just fine, on the same USB drive that I can't use for `zfs receive`. It's indeed the combination of ZFS + USB that is problematic.

I'd love to upgrade ZFS, but 0.8.3. is the latest one supported with Ubuntu 20.04. I depend on the Ubuntu 20.04 kernel as modified by Dell with drivers for my laptop.

Comment: you could try one of the unofficial ZFS PPAs for Ubuntu 20.04 (sorry, I can't recommend one since I don't use ubuntu myself, so I have no idea which ones are good or trustworthy and which are not).   zfs in ubuntu is a dkms module, so compiles against your current kernel, as long as you have the matching linux-headers-xxx package installed alongside the linux-image-xxx.

Comment: I did find this yesterday: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/zfs?field.series_filter=focal - but, like I said, I've never used it myself.  That shows a 2.1.1 package, and the PPA itself also has zfs 2.0.4 for Focal.  Do some research, check up on the PPA's owner (a Johnathan F).  His profile page on launchpad says he's been a member there since 2015 and gives contact info on IRC.  Seems legit to me.

Comment: I booted my machine from a Ubuntu 21.10 installation medium in safe mode, so I have access to zfs 2.0.6. No difference. Same behavior: after 7 GB (out of 26 GB), `zfs receive` blocks.

Comment: With zfs 2.0.6, I also see a new bug: I cannot send one of my datasets, the send fails immediately with "cannot send ...: signal received". That's just for send redirected to a file, no receive involved. Wondering if I should simply give up on ZFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the many Linux backup tools, which work for ZFS file systems exactly like for any other file system. You can still profit from ZFS by backing up snapshots rather than the current (evolving) state of the file system. The advantage is a coherent state of all files in the backup.